# * + * meaning in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
div * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

I have seen this selector a lot.
I know `div *` means to select all the children
`+` means to select all the siblings after that element

But what does it means to use `* + *`?

Comment: It means the same as `+` as you know but the element on left and right side can be anything. See this https://jsfiddle.net/yk0Lz9g2/1/

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

When you use the `+` character, you should focus on the end of your combinator statement, in this case the last `*` character in `div * + *`.
`div *` means all elements in the div. `div * +` means **adjacent** elements of all elements in the div. `div * + *` means all adjacent element of all elements in the div. To wrap this up, All element in the div tag that **proceed** other elements must receive a top margin of `1em`. For more explanation on this [The lobotomized owl selector](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls/)